# Simulating a sailboat: Rigid body angular velocity analysis

Tags: rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I'm building a simulator for a sailboat in Processing, and finding that I've forgotten quite a bit of my highschool physics.

At the moment, the part that I'm trying to nail down is the interplay between the keel and the lateral forces generated by the sail. Let's assume for the sake of argument that I'm calculating $F_L$, the lateral force correctly.

The way I approach this is that the body of the sail boat is my fulcrum, and that there are two forces acting on opposite sides of it:

$F_L$ at the center of pressure of the sail, which is *c* meters away from the body of the boat, so $\tau_L=F_L\cdot c \cdot \sin(\rho)$, where $\rho$ is the roll angle. The keel can be considered a point mass *m* that is *k* meters away from the fulcrum. $F_L$ is given to me, and I compute $\tau_k$ as follows: $k \cdot m \cdot G \cdot \sin(\rho)$.

I think I'm ok so far (unless I've messed up on the trig above). Where I'm assuming I'm getting messed up is the following:

Since by my definition $F_L$ and $F_k$ are forces acting on the same body, and are in opposite directions to each other, I treat them as scalar values to arrive at a net torque:

$$
\tau_{net}=\tau_k-\tau_L \\
\alpha_{\rho}=\frac{\tau_{net}}{m \cdot l^2}
$$

where $m \cdot l^2$ is the moment of inertia of the keel (m being its mass and l being its distance from the fulcrum). $\alpha_{\rho}$ is the angular acceleration of the keel about the fulcrum for a given roll angle $\rho$. I use that to animate my model.

Is my approach correct? Or am I mixing apples and oranges by treating the two different torque values as scalar values?

For the curious, the behavior of the model is that it swings back and forth a few times, and then starts to spin in the same direction with increasing speed.

*Edit*

Here's a couple of screenshots from the output, to give some context:
[image: No vector]

[image]

The second picture shows the two force vectors drawn.

Comment: A sketch would go a long way here...

Comment: I assume that dot between m and $l^2$ is just standard multiplication?

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing in you model that makes you think it is wrong.

Comment: @JMLCarter yes, it's not a dot product. And the behavior is described in the question - it swings back and forth a few times, and then starts to spin in the same direction with increasing speed.

Comment: It swings and spins on a horizontal axis pointing in the direction of travel?

Comment: Is the vessel sitting on your co-ordinate origin? (i.e. do we need to be concerned about sign changes as it tilts).

Comment: @JMLCarter yes to both. I've gotten more expected behavior by introducing a "drag" factor, but I don't like having to do it. It feels more like a bandaid than a solution.

Comment: It should be quick enough to try moving it to, say, 10,10,10, so no vectors go negative.

Comment: @JMLCarter I'm not sure what good that will do, since the sign of the vector has nothing do with the relative position of the boat, just its orientation.

Comment: It shouldn't have any affect on your physics, if it does there is a code error somewhere

Comment: It seems to me that your trig is messed up. You need $\cos\rho$ , not $\sin\rho$, because the torque due to the lateral force will be greatest when $\rho$ is smallest (i.e. when the boat is fully upright). But maybe a diagram would show me why $\sin$ is the right function.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that when the hull tips the center of bouancy moves downwind. This increases the effectiveness of both the keel and the upwind, elevated portion of the boat in providing torque to counter the effects of the wind on the sail. The sail, however, is closer to the tilted center of bouancy than it is to the geomentric center of the hull, and it's torque is reduced.